How to Create a React Application with Electron.js and Addons Without Using Webpack?
Could someone help me with this? I'm making an application with Electron.js, React, and addons. I've had problems with the make process as it doesn't recognize the addon's path. After doing some tests, I found that the issue is with webpack, so I decided to create the application without a bundler. Does anyone know how to make a React application without a bundler? Only using Babel and React. A repository on this would be very helpful.
I tried to create the app with yarn add react react-dom and babel
